# Error: Failed to initialize react-native-reanimated library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, react-native-reanimated

I was working on a project on react native trying to create drawer navigation

- I installed a navigation drawer, gesture handler, and reanimated libraries
- and when I run I got an error
  1st error :

  ERROR  Error: Failed to initialize react-native-reanimated library, make sure you followed installation steps here: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/

  1. Make sure reanimated's babel plugin is installed in your babel.config.js (you should have 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' listed there - also see the above link for details)
  2. Make sure you reset build cache after updating the config, run: yarn start --reset-cache, js engine: hermes

so I did according to the suggestion in this error I added plugins:['react-native-reanimated/plugin' in the babel.config.js and started with npm start ----reset cache  that gave me another error:

2nd error

```
error: index.js: Unknown option: .Plugins. Check out https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-core/#options for more information about options.
```

here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Train",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.1",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.1",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.3.4",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.17.0",
    "react-navigation-stack": "^2.10.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.72.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

my index.js

```
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Home from './pages/Home';
import cart from './pages/Drawer/cart';
import items from './pages/Drawer/items';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

my babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
  Plugins:['react-native-reanimated/plugin'],//I added this line because of the 1st error 
};
```

my app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack';
import {createDrawerNavigator} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

//for stack
import Login from './pages/Login';
import Home from './pages/Home';
//for drawer
import cart from './pages/Drawer/cart';
import items from './pages/Drawer/items';
import wallet from './pages/Drawer/wallet';
import orders from './pages/Drawer/orders';


const stack = createStackNavigator();
const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

function MystackNav(){
  return(
    <stack.Navigator>
      <stack.Screen name='Login' component={Login} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
      <stack.Screen name='Home' component={Home} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
      <stack.Screen name='Drawer' component={MyDrawer}/>
    </stack.Navigator>
  )
}

function MyDrawer(){
  return(
    <Drawer.Navigator>
      <Drawer.Screen name='cart' component={cart}/>
    </Drawer.Navigator>
  )
}

export default function App(){
  return(
    <NavigationContainer>
      <MystackNav/>
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: lowercase 'p' (plugin) in babel.config.js?

Comment: Yes as @JácintVarga says the second error will disappear with lowercase, but then you will return back to the first one most probably

Comment: Did you find a way to resolve this?

Comment: If you have other plugins defined/listed, ensure that you listed `'react-native-reanimated/plugin'` last

Comment: This issue on my end seems to have fixed itself. I did most of the changes suggested by this thread and others and after a few restarts it was suddenly fixed. Then I undid the changes one by one to see which one had been the fix, but nothing caused the error to come back and now I am at where I started before applying any fixes except the drawer navigator works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Mine is working the only diff is:

`babel.config.js`

```
module.exports = function(api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: ['react-native-reanimated/plugin']
  };
};
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "awesomeproject2",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "node_modules/expo/AppEntry.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "expo start",
    "android": "expo start --android",
    "ios": "expo start --ios",
    "web": "expo start --web"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.4.0",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^6.5.0",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.13",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.2",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.2.0",
    "expo": "^46.0.16",
    "expo-status-bar": "^1.4.0",
    "react": "~18.1.0",
    "react-native": "^0.70.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.11.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.18.9",
    "babel-preset-expo": "^9.2.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Answer (score 16):

1.Update babel.config.js

```
  module.exports = {
    presets: [
      ...
    ],
    plugins: [
      ...
      'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
    ],
  };
```

2.run `expo start -c`

**references** - https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/

Answer (score 6):

***tl/dr:*** suspect I resolved this by running `npx expo start --clear` instead off `npm start --reset-cache` after adding `'react-native-reanimated/plugin'` to babel plugins

I had this error same error when trying to run my app using expo go on android:

```
ERROR  Error: Failed to initialize react-native-reanimated library, make sure you followed installation steps here: https://docs.swmansion.com/react-native-reanimated/docs/fundamentals/installation/       
1) Make sure reanimated's babel plugin is installed in your babel.config.js (you should have 'react-native-reanimated/plugin' listed there - also see the above link for details)
2) Make sure you reset build cache after updating the config, run: yarn start --reset-cache
ERROR  Invariant Violation: "main" has not been registered. This can happen if:
* Metro (the local dev server) is run from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
* A module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` wasn't called.
```

According to the guide I just needed update the babel.config.js as mentioned by multiple people above, though this did not work.

However it started working for me when I followed the section on the guide for updating for web support. https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/reanimated/#installation

```
plugins: [    
  '@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from',
  'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
],
```

Followed but running:

```
npx expo start --clear
```

I suspect what fixed it was using `npx expo start --clear`, as previously I had been using `npm start --reset-cache` instead.

Answer (score 1):

1. Update babel.config.js

`$module.exports = { presets: [ ... ], plugins: [ ... 'react-native-reanimated/plugin', ], };`

2. Update App.js

`$import "react-native-gesture-handler";`
add import top of the app.js

3. run `$ npx expo start -c`

Answer (score 0):

After adding the "plugins: ["react-native-reanimated/plugin"]," to the babel.config file

Save it and stop the server if running.

Then clear the cache.

Assuming you are using expo

type "npx expo start -c"

Then re-run the dev server and reload
It should take sometime

That's how mine worked

Comment: did you get a warning about not having the correct versions of react-native-pager-view and react-native-reanimated - see my answer

Comment: I can't remember if there was a warning

Comment: Is your issue sorted without my fix(es)?

Comment: yes my issue has been sorted

Comment: Nice one ))) <-- smile

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error after installing the react-native-reanimated and adding the babel plugin to my babel.config.js.

I solved it by stopping the server the run this command

```
npm start -- --clear
```

Answer (score 0):

Expo related

I followed the babel.config fixes mentioned on the reanimated installation guide which didn't fix the issue.

when I ran `npx expo start --clear` i received this message in the bash terminal

```
Starting project at C:\Users\****\development\******-**\frontend\****-**
Some dependencies are incompatible with the installed expo version:
  react-native-pager-view@6.2.0 - expected version: 6.1.2
  react-native-reanimated@3.3.0 - expected version: ~2.14.4     
Your project may not work correctly until you install the correct versions of the packages.
Install individual packages by running npx expo install react-native-pager-view@6.1.2 react-native-reanimated@~2.14.4
```

so then I ran `yarn add react-native-pager-view@6.1.2 react-native-reanimated@~2.14.4` as I'm using yarn not npm ( npm version -> `npm install react-native-pager-view@6.1.2 react-native-reanimated@~2.14.4`) and this fixed my issue which was due to my version of Expo's dependency requirements/limitations.

After downgrading and with my babel config set up as such (a previous warning mentioned not having this plugin installed `'@babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from'` so I added it to the plugins array BEFORE reanimated - by the way there was a mention that the reanimated plugin has to be listed last too!)

```
module.exports = function (api) {
api.cache(true);
return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo','module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: ['expo-router/babel','react-native-paper/babel','@babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from','react-native-reanimated/plugin'],
};
```

};

**KEY POINTS**

- downgrade to correct versions - `npx expo start` can help
- install and use the `@babel/plugin-transform-export-namespace-from` if you see this error when tring to start your server
- list the reanimated plugin last in your babel config

Answer (score 0):

For react native bare project:

running `yarn start --reset-cache` or `npx react-native start --reset-cache` worked

Answer (score 0):

1. Go inside the node modules and look for react-native-reanimated package.
2. Check the version of react-native used by the package inside package.json.
3. Switch to the same version of react native in your main project and do a cleanup by resetting the metro cache `yarn start --reset-cache` and android clean as well `cd android && ./gradlew clean && cd..`
4. `yarn` and then `yarn android`

Answer (score 0):

If you really are on the edge of despair, I have had this error many times in all sorts of (mostly obscure) forms (function not found, something is undefined, something is null, blah blah).

Systematically check whether you have **different versions** of the library in your entire code base (also `node_modules`, recursively). If so, it might help to put a `resolution` block in your `package.json`:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "17",
    "react-native-reanimated": "3.6.1"
  }
```

Good luck and stay positive...!